# Table without the name "Table" in the head.

Tags: floats, captions

If I write

```
\caption{This is the table.}
```

in a tabular environment, then the head of the table 
will appear as:

```
"Table #: This is the table."
```

But I want the head of my table to be simply

```
"This is the table."
```

ie. without numbering or the word Table before it. What is the easiest
way to do that? I really cant find any reference on google on how 
to do that.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it). You can also use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `caption` package and then `\caption*{<the caption text>}` instead of the normal `\caption`.